# NHibernate and mysql timestamp

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to do versioning with NHibernate and everything works fine, however right after the insert NHibernate tries to pull the generated timestamp by executing the following query:

```
SELECT profileloc_.Updated as Updated14_ FROM profile_locale profileloc_ 
WHERE profileloc_.id=?p0 and profileloc_.culture=?p1;?p0 = 16, ?p1 = 1033
```

Which is totally wrong, as it will pull out **all** versions starting with the **first** one.

How do I make it add `ORDER BY Updated DESC` to this query? I am using Fluent NHibernate for mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I put `.Generated.Never()` on the timestamp property generation moves to NHibernate from MySQL and so the issue disappears. However, I prefer it to be on MySQL side if possible.